# Is there a way to measure the size or length of an object in a general way?

Tags: java, generics, size, string-length

For example, with `String x`, the number of characters can be measured through `x.length()`
Similarly with an ArrayList the size of it can be met with `.size()` method.

I want setting up a for loop that can go through different types of objects.

Comment: Treating strings and collections in the same way doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: they were just examples that came to mind when wanting to get the size of an object

Comment: @sysoDOTspace What do you mean by size?  size in bytes, size in elements, memory used, size when serialized?

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Sure. A huge if block, testing various possibilities, would be the most basic (and ugly) idea, of course. Another way would be to use reflection and look for a `size()` method, for example. Also not really pretty.

Unfortunately (for you), these classes do not share a common interface, since the `sice()` method has very distinct meanings in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

> I want setting up a for loop that can go through different types of objects.

As has already been mentioned, size/length may have different meanings per type and often even for one type depending on the semantics, e.g. the size in memory vs. the number of characters in a string etc.

Besides that looping over those elements via size/length + index would be hard since the methods that use that index differ as well, e.g. `charAt(idx)` for strings vs. `get(idx)` for lists. Addionally access by index is not always possible, e.g. for sets.

Besides that, what you're probably after it the use of `Iterable<T>` which would allow you to use a foreach loop, i.e. looping over all elements using an implicit readonly iterator.

Something like this:

```
<T> void loop(Iterable<T> i) {
  for( T element : i ) {
    //whatever
  }
}
```

This wouldn't work out of the box for strings though, because you can only get primitive arrays for them and thus you'd need a wrapper that "translates" between a `char[]` and an `Iterable<Character>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, All objects might have different meaning for length/size. For a List, size means number of elements inside it, and a String length represents number of characters in the String. Both although analogues are different.

Hence, there is no such common method. size/length may have different meaning in different cases.

You may want to define a common interface which is extended by all your desired classes and define such methods in each of sub classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to do it, but you can try Java Reflection.

Here is a sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Sample input
    List<Object> inputList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    inputList.add("This is a String");
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
    tmp.add("A");
    tmp.add("B");
    tmp.add("C");
    inputList.add(tmp);
    inputList.add(new Integer(0));

    // Create a map that hold the Class to Method relationship
    Map<String, String> classMethodPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    classMethodPairs.put("java.lang.String", "length");
    classMethodPairs.put("java.util.ArrayList", "size");
    // ... Add other class and method you like to use in the loop

    // Go through the list of input objects
    for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++) {

        Object aObj = inputList.get(i);

        // Find out the class name of the object
        String aObjClassName = aObj.getClass().getName();

        // Find out the method corresponding to the class from the map
        String sizeMethodName = classMethodPairs.get(aObjClassName);

        if (sizeMethodName != null) {

            try {

                // Get the method object
                Method sizeMethod = aObj.getClass().getMethod(sizeMethodName);

                // Use the method object to get the size
                System.out.println(aObjClassName + " == " + sizeMethod.invoke(aObj));                   

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {

                System.err.println("Class " + aObjClassName + " does not has method " + sizeMethodName);
            } 

        } else {
            System.err.println("Unable to handle class " + aObjClassName);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

java.lang.String == 16

java.util.ArrayList == 3

Unable to handle class java.lang.Integer

More about Java Reflection:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/